# UICollectionView cells do not take up width of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

The UICollectionView width will change per device as it is constrained to reach the horizontal margins of the View. The collectionView's layout is Flow. The only reason I am using a UICollectionView is to space images evenly across on different device sizes, and all of these images will have a tap gesture recogniser. And the amount of rows is variable, as the amount of image icons will vary. Apparently this is the method I am after:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth/6, height: collectionViewWidth/6);
}
```

I have tried to do it like this:

```
var collectionViewWidth: CGFloat = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.dataSource = self
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    collectionViewWidth = collectionView.collectionViewLayout
        .collectionViewContentSize().width
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth/6, height: collectionViewWidth/6);
}
```

But nothing I try in code makes any difference at all to the final output which is this (forget about the images that are not in the UICollectionView - they will be deleted):

[image]

I changed the size of the cells in the interface builder and the result got me this:

[image]

So I have two questions:

Why do the cells in the above picture not go to the edge of the UICollectionView?

How can I set the cell size programmatically at run time to make my UICollectionView have 6 columns on all device sizes?

Here is all the code for my ViewController that contains the UICollectionView:

```
import UIKit

class DressingRoomViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    let identifier = "cellIdentifier"
    let dataSource = DataSource()
    var collectionViewWidth: CGFloat = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        collectionViewWidth = collectionView.collectionViewLayout
            .collectionViewContentSize().width
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(  segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
                                    sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "dressingRoom2MyOutfits") {
            let myOutfitsViewController = segue.destinationViewController
                as! MyOutfitsViewController
        }
    }
}



// MARK:- UICollectionViewDataSource Delegate
extension DressingRoomViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(
        collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            return dataSource.groups.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return dataSource.numbeOfRowsInEachGroup(section)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(
            identifier,forIndexPath:indexPath) as! FruitCell

        let fruits: [Fruit] = dataSource.fruitsInGroup(indexPath.section)
        let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]

        let name = fruit.name!

        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: name)
        cell.caption.text = name.capitalizedString

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth/6, height: collectionViewWidth/6);
    }
}
```

It may be worth mentioning that my data source of the UICollectionView is grouped only because I was doing a tutorial. Here is the DataSource code:

class DataSource {

```
init() {
    populateData()
}

var fruits:[Fruit] = []
var groups:[String] = []

func numbeOfRowsInEachGroup(index: Int) -> Int {
    return fruitsInGroup(index).count
}

func numberOfGroups() -> Int {
    return groups.count
}

func gettGroupLabelAtIndex(index: Int) -> String {
    return groups[index]
}

// MARK:- Populate Data from plist

func populateData() {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(
        "Fruits", ofType: "plist") {
            if let dictArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) {
                for item in dictArray {
                    if let dict = item as? NSDictionary {
                        let name = dict["name"] as! String
                        let group = dict["group"] as! String

                        let fruit = Fruit(name: name, group: group)
                        if !contains(groups, group){
                            groups.append(group)
                        }
                        fruits.append(fruit)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

// MARK:- FruitsForEachGroup

func fruitsInGroup(index: Int) -> [Fruit] {
    let item = groups[index]
    let filteredFruits = fruits.filter { (fruit: Fruit) -> Bool in
        return fruit.group == item
    }
    return filteredFruits
}
```

}

And here is the plist that gets loaded into the data source:

[image]

**EDIT: I have done some work to remove the groups as they were unneeded. I see the groups were causing the new rows to start too soon. I changed the code to this:**

```
    // MARK:- UICollectionViewDataSource Delegate
extension DressingRoomViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(
        collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 12
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(
            identifier,forIndexPath:indexPath) as! FruitCell

        let fruits: [Fruit] = dataSource.fruits
        let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]

        let name = fruit.name!

        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: name)
        cell.caption.text = name.capitalizedString

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
            return CGSize(width: 200, height: 200);
    }
}
```

[image]

**Now I just need to make the cell width 1/6 of the collection view width somehow and then crop off the bottom of the UICollectioview that is just wasted space**

Comment: Have you ever used a collection view before? - Also, let me ask you this: have you tried setting breakpoints or logging to see in what order things are happening? What if the collection view sets itself up _before_ your `viewDidAppear:` configures your width value? Could that be happening?

Comment: @matt No I haven't. I'm new to iOS. I have completed the  [iOS with Swift track](https://teamtreehouse.com/tracks/ios-development-with-swift) on Team Treehouse, and now I am making my first app on my own. I just put a breakpoint after the collectViewWidth variable is set and it gets set to 288 on an iPhone4. But the `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
            return CGSize(width: 20, height: 20);
    }` function never fires a breakpoint. Maybe it is not meant to, as is just configuring the collectionView.

Comment: @matt I have tried hardcoding values into the above function that sets the cell size and it did not change the output

Comment: I would suggest learning about collection views before trying to mess with them in weird ways. Meanwhile, I've given an answer that I hope will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the itemSize of the collectionViewLayout in viewDidLoad as shown in this example:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size
        let nrOfCellsPerRow = 6 
        let itemWidth = collectionViewSize.width/nrOfCellsPerRow
        let itemHeight = 80 // example
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight) 
    }
```

If you want to have spacing between the cells you will have to compensate the itemWidth calculation

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a UICollectionViewFlowLayout, the way you configure the width of the cells is by talking to *the UICollectionViewFlowLayout*. Set its `itemSize`.

Answer (score 0):

For layout, we basically prefers to create a CustomflowLayout, inherited from [UICollectionViewFlowlayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html) and oveeride it's 2 methods:

- layoutAttributesForElementsInRect: (required)
- layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: (required)

And then set

[self.collectionview setFlowlayout:CustomflowLayout];